# what would happen ,if I wait for a closed mutex?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

what would happen ,if I wait for a closed mutex?

```
DWORD WINAPI Fun2Proc(LPVOID lpParameter   // thread data)  
{
    while(TRUE)  
    {  
       WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE);   //what would happen here?

       Sleep(1000);  

       ReleaseMutex(hMutex);  
    }  

    return 0;  
} 
HANDLE hMutex;
int main(){
HANDLE hThread2;  
hMutex=CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE,"tickets");
CloseHandle(hMutex);    //  and closed here
hThread2=CreateThread(NULL,0,Fun2Proc,NULL,0,NULL);  
CloseHandle(hThread2);  
......
}
```

Comment: The better question: What **did** happen when you ran this code?

Comment: You would possibly know the answer if you had evaluated the return value of WaitForSingleObject.

Comment: What would happen?  Well, strictly speaking, anything `could` happen, since you're invoking undefined behaviour.  Windows would be perfectly justified in killing your program immediately, or making ants eat your main window, or anything.  (In practice, it's probably either going to generate an error or wait indefinitely.  But it's still a bad idea.)

Answer (score 2):

`CloseHandle(hMutex)`is done **before** the thread is created. Consequently the handle to the mutex is invalid and according to the code shown here, the result is definitely the following:

- `WaitForSingleObject` immediately returns **WAIT_FAILED** (0xFFFFFFFF): The function has failed. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
- and a call to `GetLastError` will show **ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE** (0x6): The handle is invalid.

**Advice:** Always evaluate return values of API call properly. MSDN provides easy to understand documentation.

Comment: ... and what was the question? Check the return value of `ReleaseMutex(hMutex)` right after calling `CloseHandle(hMutex)`. I'd expect the return value to be ZERO. And GetLastError will show ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE.

Answer (score 1):

After "CloseHandle" the value of "hMutex" is not valid any more so WaitForSingleObject() should return WAIT_FAILED and GetLastError() should return an error code indicating that the handle is invalid.

However in the meantime Windows may have assigned the handle to another object. Maybe now the value still stored in "hMutex" identifies some object that has been created internally by CreateThread(). In this case WaitForSingleObject() will wait for that object.

It is not a good idea writing code in a way that it is possible to wait for a "closed handle" because of the possibility that the handle has been re-assigned to another object in the meantime.